# Trigonometric Indefinite Integration

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Integrate:

$$\int\frac{\cos5x+\cos4x}{1-2\cos 3x}\; dx$$

I tried using sums and products formula but couldn't make it. How to approach this problem?

Comment: Whatever you try ,you should add your try with question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\cos x =\frac {e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} $$
Or

Multiply and divide by $\sin \left (\frac {3x}{2}\right )$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. By using De Moivre's formula
$$
e^{ix}=\cos x+i \sin x
$$ one may prove that
$$
\frac{\cos 5x+\cos 4x}{1-2\cos 3x} =-\cos x-\cos (2x)
$$ then the integral is easier to evalute.